# Implement SQL unicode search in Entity Framework using contain

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, unicode

I am trying to search my `users` with this query :

```
dbcontext.tbluserinfo .where(i=>i.name.contain("مهرپو");
```

I have a record with this value in my database, but the query doesn't return the result.

So I tried to write my query in SQL Server like this:

```
select *
from tbluserinfo 
where name like '%مهرپو%'
```

again no result is returned!

But when I changed this to :

```
 select *
 from tbluserinfo 
 where name like N'%مهرپو%'
```

The result is returned.

So my question is how can I put `N` before my `searchvalue` using `EF`, and second question is I just have this problem for this value `مهرپو` and for other users it works fine - why?

Comment: what is your collation setting in the database options ?

Comment: what does you mean?which setting?

Comment: btw do you use EF code first to generate the db ? if not what is the name column data type ?